# How to assemble the following code base in the Canvas based analog clock with Clockface having 28 hours and 112 minutes

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

The hours will shift when the minute hand hits 56 minutes in the 112 minute clock.(the position on 56 will be 14th hour as per the following code.

We tried many solutions through many days and finally had a breakthrough with the help of Kaiido from Stackoverflow community. It has become a complete solution for the first part of our clock system for Moon.

We currently blocked in the step of assembling the digital values into the analog Canvas clock system. The purpose of this clocks work is to fulfill an ambition of helping & joining hands with the scientific community. Your contribution with our efforts is highly respected.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var radius = canvas.height / 2;
ctx.translate(radius, radius);
radius = radius * 0.90
setInterval(drawClock, 1000);

function drawClock() {
  drawFace(ctx, radius);
  drawNumbers(ctx, radius);
  drawTime(ctx, radius);
}

function drawFace(ctx, radius) {
  var grad;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fill();
  grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0, 0, radius * 0.95, 0, 0, radius * 1.05);
  grad.addColorStop(0, '#333');
  grad.addColorStop(0.5, 'white');
  grad.addColorStop(1, '#333');
  ctx.strokeStyle = grad;
  ctx.lineWidth = radius * 0.1;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius * 0.1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#333';
  ctx.fill();
}

function drawNumbers(ctx, radius) {
  var ang;
  var num;
  ctx.font = radius * 0.08 + "px arial";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  for (num = 1; num < 29; num++) {
    ang = num * Math.PI / 14;
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, -radius * 0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
    ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, radius * 0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
  }
}

function drawTime(ctx, radius) {
  var now = new Date();
  var hour = now.getHours();
  var minute = now.getMinutes();
  var second = now.getSeconds();
  //hour
  hour = hour % 12;
  hour = (hour * Math.PI / 6) +
    (minute * Math.PI / (6 * 60)) +
    (second * Math.PI / (360 * 60));
  drawHand(ctx, hour, radius * 0.5, radius * 0.07);
  //minute
  minute = (minute * Math.PI / 30) + (second * Math.PI / (30 * 60));
  drawHand(ctx, minute, radius * 0.8, radius * 0.07);
  // second
  second = (second * Math.PI / 30);
  drawHand(ctx, second, radius * 0.9, radius * 0.02);
}

function drawHand(ctx, pos, length, width) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = width;
  ctx.lineCap = "round";
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.rotate(pos);
  ctx.lineTo(0, -length);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.rotate(-pos);
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" style="background-color:#333">
</canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

```
    The values are to be inserted from the following code base, where the  
    minutes seconds and hours run using the following format,

    28 hours = 1 day
    56 mins = 1 hour
    56 seconds = 1 minute
```

```js
// our constants
var ms_per_sec = 1000; // 1000
var sec_per_min = 56; // 55.54920598892;
var min_per_hr = 56; // 55.54920598892;
var hrs_per_day = 28;

// let's make our target date at some fixed distance in our own time system
var countDownDate = new Date().getTime() +
(1 * hrs_per_day * min_per_hr * sec_per_min * ms_per_sec) + // 1 day
(2 * min_per_hr * sec_per_min * ms_per_sec) + // two hours
(1 * sec_per_min * ms_per_sec) + // 1 minutes
(5 * ms_per_sec); // 5 seconds


// Update the count down every frame
function loop() {
  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var total_ms = (countDownDate + now);
  // from here our values are based on our own time system
  var total_seconds = (total_ms / ms_per_sec);
  var total_minutes = (total_seconds/ sec_per_min);
  var total_hours = (total_minutes / min_per_hr);
  var total_days = (total_hours / hrs_per_day);
  
  var days = Math.floor(total_days);
  var hours = Math.floor(total_hours % hrs_per_day);
  var minutes = Math.floor(total_minutes % 112);
  var seconds = Math.floor(total_seconds % sec_per_min);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").textContent = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (total_ms < 0) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    return;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
 }
 loop();
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<div id="demo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
    The problem faced is that the analog clock has a settimeInterval that  
    makes the looped code execute at a faster rate, messing with the time of  
    the clock. Is there a way to execute the analog clock in a cleaner way.

    We are happy to have arrived at the solution for the digital clock with                                 
    the help of the stackoverflow community. The hours assembled in the 
    digital clock are running perfectly as expected. We are looking forward 
    to the solution on the analog clock. Your help towards our Research work 
    with ourmoonlife is highly respected. We consider our work to be the 
    common property of this planet, we welcome you to join hands with us.
    Thanks for the wonderful opportunity.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the correct logic to get your time in Hour:Minutes:Seconds format.

To draw it as an analogous clock, you just have to convert these values to angle.

On 12h clocks, we do `((Math.PI * 2) / 12) * (hour % 12)`, or more literally, `(full_circle / number_of_hours_per_circle) * (hour % number_of_hours_per_circle)`.

In your project, you have 28 hours per day, so you could try to make a 14hrs clock to keep AM/PM format, but you're not forced to.
Now, your rounded 56 minutes per hours maps pretty well with the 28 hours per day (4 minutes pet tick on a AM/PM clock, or 2 minutes per tick on a 28H clock), but beware that your original 
`55.54920598892` wouldn't map so well.

```js
// our constants
var ms_per_sec = 1000; // 1000
var sec_per_min = 56; // 55.54920598892;
var min_per_hr = 56; // 55.54920598892;
var hrs_per_day = 28;

// let's make our target date at some fixed distance in our own time system
var countDownDate = new Date().getTime() +
(1 * hrs_per_day * min_per_hr * sec_per_min * ms_per_sec) + // 1 day
(2 * min_per_hr * sec_per_min * ms_per_sec) + // two hours
(1 * sec_per_min * ms_per_sec) + // 1 minutes
(5 * ms_per_sec); // 5 seconds


// Update the count down every frame
function loop() {
  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var total_ms = (countDownDate + now);
  // from here our values are based on our own time system
  var total_seconds = (total_ms / ms_per_sec);
  var total_minutes = (total_seconds/ sec_per_min);
  var total_hours = (total_minutes / min_per_hr);
  var total_days = (total_hours / hrs_per_day);
  
  var days = Math.floor(total_days);
  var hours = Math.floor(total_hours % hrs_per_day);
  var minutes = Math.floor(total_minutes % 112);
  var seconds = Math.floor(total_seconds % sec_per_min);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  draw(hours, minutes, seconds);
    
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (total_ms < 0) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    return;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
 }


var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var radius = canvas.height / 2;
radius = radius * 0.90

function draw(hours, minutes, seconds) {
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  ctx.translate(canvas.height / 2, canvas.height / 2);
  drawFace(ctx, radius);
  drawNumbers(ctx, radius);
  drawTime(ctx, radius, hours, minutes, seconds);
}

function drawFace(ctx, radius) {
  var grad;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fill();
  grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0, 0, radius * 0.95, 0, 0, radius * 1.05);
  grad.addColorStop(0, '#333');
  grad.addColorStop(0.5, 'white');
  grad.addColorStop(1, '#333');
  ctx.strokeStyle = grad;
  ctx.lineWidth = radius * 0.1;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius * 0.1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#333';
  ctx.fill();
}

function drawNumbers(ctx, radius) {
  var ang;
  var num;
  ctx.font = radius * 0.08 + "px arial";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  for (num = 1; num < 29; num++) {
    ang = num * Math.PI / 14;
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, -radius * 0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
    ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, radius * 0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
  }
}

function drawTime(ctx, radius, hours, minutes, seconds) {
  const angle_hours = getAngle(hours, hrs_per_day);
  drawHand(ctx, angle_hours, radius * 0.5, radius * 0.07);
  //minute
  const angle_minutes = getAngle(minutes, min_per_hr);
  drawHand(ctx, angle_minutes, radius * 0.8, radius * 0.07);
  // second
  const angle_seconds = getAngle(seconds, sec_per_min);
  drawHand(ctx, angle_seconds, radius * 0.9, radius * 0.02);
}

function getAngle(value, max) {
  return (Math.PI*2 / max) * value;
}

function drawHand(ctx, pos, length, width) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = width;
  ctx.lineCap = "round";
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.rotate(pos);
  ctx.lineTo(0, -length);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.rotate(-pos);
}

 loop();
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" style="background-color:#333">
</canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

And if you want the 14H AM/PM variant:

```js
// our constants
var ms_per_sec = 1000; // 1000
var sec_per_min = 56; // 55.54920598892;
var min_per_hr = 56; // 55.54920598892;
var hrs_per_day = 28;

// let's make our target date at some fixed distance in our own time system
var countDownDate = new Date().getTime() +
(1 * hrs_per_day * min_per_hr * sec_per_min * ms_per_sec) + // 1 day
(2 * min_per_hr * sec_per_min * ms_per_sec) + // two hours
(1 * sec_per_min * ms_per_sec) + // 1 minutes
(5 * ms_per_sec); // 5 seconds


// Update the count down every frame
function loop() {
  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var total_ms = (countDownDate + now);
  // from here our values are based on our own time system
  var total_seconds = (total_ms / ms_per_sec);
  var total_minutes = (total_seconds/ sec_per_min);
  var total_hours = (total_minutes / min_per_hr);
  var total_days = (total_hours / hrs_per_day);
  
  var days = Math.floor(total_days);
  var hours = Math.floor(total_hours % hrs_per_day);
  var minutes = Math.floor(total_minutes % 112);
  var seconds = Math.floor(total_seconds % sec_per_min);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  draw(hours, minutes, seconds);
    
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (total_ms < 0) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    return;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
 }


var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var radius = canvas.height / 2;
radius = radius * 0.90

function draw(hours, minutes, seconds) {
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  ctx.translate(canvas.height / 2, canvas.height / 2);
  drawFace(ctx, radius);
  drawNumbers(ctx, radius);
  drawTime(ctx, radius, hours, minutes, seconds);
}

function drawFace(ctx, radius) {
  var grad;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fill();
  grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0, 0, radius * 0.95, 0, 0, radius * 1.05);
  grad.addColorStop(0, '#333');
  grad.addColorStop(0.5, 'white');
  grad.addColorStop(1, '#333');
  ctx.strokeStyle = grad;
  ctx.lineWidth = radius * 0.1;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius * 0.1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#333';
  ctx.fill();
}

function drawNumbers(ctx, radius) {
  var ang;
  var num;
  ctx.font = radius * 0.08 + "px arial";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  for (num = 1; num < 15; num++) {
    ang = num * Math.PI / (14/2);
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, -radius * 0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
    ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, radius * 0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
  }
}

function drawTime(ctx, radius, hours, minutes, seconds) {
  const angle_hours = getAngle(hours % hrs_per_day/2, hrs_per_day/2);
  drawHand(ctx, angle_hours, radius * 0.5, radius * 0.07);
  //minute
  const angle_minutes = getAngle(minutes, min_per_hr);
  drawHand(ctx, angle_minutes, radius * 0.8, radius * 0.07);
  // second
  const angle_seconds = getAngle(seconds, sec_per_min);
  drawHand(ctx, angle_seconds, radius * 0.9, radius * 0.02);
}

function getAngle(value, max) {
  return (Math.PI*2 / max) * value;
}

function drawHand(ctx, pos, length, width) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = width;
  ctx.lineCap = "round";
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.rotate(pos);
  ctx.lineTo(0, -length);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.rotate(-pos);
}

 loop();
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" style="background-color:#333">
</canvas>
</body>

</html>
```